# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-simple-table, despite the table seemingly loading correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the latest release of vuetify 3 with vue 3, and getting the warning in the title, but optically the table is loading correctly. What might be causing this?

The component containing the table:

```
<template>

      <div class="right-bar text-no-wrap" style="overflow-x: scroll">
          <v-simple-table id="myTable">
            <template v-slot:default>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-left font-weight-regular">Item</th>
                  <th class="text-right font-weight-regular font-italic pl-3">Unit</th>
                  <th class="text-right font-weight-regular pl-3">Total</th>
                  <th class="text-right font-weight-regular pl-3" v-for="period in dataset.modelPeriods" :key="period">Period {{ period }}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </template>
          </v-simple-table>
        </div>
  
</template>

<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { computed } from '@vue/runtime-core'

export default {
    setup() {

      const store = useStore()

      const dataset = computed (
        () => store.state.dataset
      )

      return { dataset }

    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

My vuetify.js file:

```
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify(
  // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
)
```

Comment: Vuetify 3 is in beta, it's documentation is [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tables/).  Since there is no mention of `v-simple-table` anywhere I would assume that they haven't yet fully ported it over from Vuetify 2

Comment: Thanks, replacing v-simple-table with v-table helped. Interestingly I only started receiving this warning recently, even though I've been using vuetify beta 3 for a while.